# Sequelize Unknown column '*.createdAt' in 'field list'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting a Unknown column 'userDetails.createdAt' in 'field list'
When trying to fetch with association.

Using `findAll` without association works fine.

My code is as follows:

```js
var userDetails = sequelize.define('userDetails', {
    userId :Sequelize.INTEGER,
    firstName : Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName : Sequelize.STRING,
    birthday : Sequelize.DATE
});

var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING
});

user.hasOne(userDetails, {foreignKey: 'userId'});

user.findAll({include: [userDetails] }).success(function(user) {
    console.log(user)
});
```

Answer (score 295, accepted):

I think the error is that you have timestamps enabled in sequelize, but your actual table definitions in the DB do not contain a timestamp column.

When you do user.find it will just do `SELECT user.*`, which only takes the columns you actually have. But when you join, each column of the joined table will be aliased, which creates the following query:

```
SELECT `users`.*, `userDetails`.`userId` AS `userDetails.userId`,`userDetails`.`firstName` AS `userDetails.firstName`,`userDetails`.`lastName` AS `userDetails.lastName`, `userDetails`.`birthday` AS `userDetails.birthday`, `userDetails`.`id` AS `userDetails.id`, `userDetails`.`createdAt` AS `userDetails.createdAt`, `userDetails`.`updatedAt` AS `userDetails.updatedAt` FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `userDetails` AS `userDetails` ON `users`.`id` = `userDetails`.`userId`;
```

The fix would be to disable timestamps for either the userDetails model:

```
var userDetails = sequelize.define('userDetails', {
    userId :Sequelize.INTEGER,
    firstName : Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName : Sequelize.STRING,
    birthday : Sequelize.DATE
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
```

or for all models:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('sequelize_test', 'root', null, {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect: 'mysql',
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesnt make sense because thats not how a sequelize model looks anymore. after the field list is class and instancemethods

Comment: This is quite annoying. I was having no problem, `timestamps: false` was enough, but suddenly the Sequelize added a` .createdAt` to the SELECT of a specific table, in a foreign key column. Then I needed to include `define: { timestamps: false }` in the Sequelize instantiation and it worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

I got the same error when migrating our project from laravel to featherjs. Tables are having column names created_at, updated_at instead of createdat, updatedat.  I had to use field name mapping in Sequelize models as given below

```
  const users = sequelize.define('users', {
     id: {
         type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
         primaryKey: true
     },
     createdAt: {
         field: 'created_at',
         type: Sequelize.DATE,
     },
     updatedAt: {
         field: 'updated_at',
         type: Sequelize.DATE,
     },
     ..
     ..
     ..
     ..
```

Answer (score 9):

I got same error,two solutions：

1. when create table, add created_at and updated_at column.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user name',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'created time',
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'updated time',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='user';
```

2. disable timestamps

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
   title: Sequelize.STRING,
   description: Sequelize.TEXT
 },{
   timestamps: false
 })
```

Answer (score 8):

In the general config this helped:

```
{
  timestamps: true,
}
```

After

```
{
  timestamps: true,
  underscored: true,
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For postgresql:**

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@url:port/dbname',{ 
    define:{
        timestamps: false
    }
})
```

Needless to say, replace `user`,`pass`,`url`,`port` and `dbname` values with your configuration values.

Answer (score 3):

Disable timestamps
Ex:-

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    firstName : Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName : Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well, maybe too late but you can create createdAt, updatedAt when migration like

```
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now'),
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now'),
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
```

Im using express and sequelize mysql
then the model just define like normal
for ex:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.TEXT,
    consider: DataTypes.TEXT,
    otherQuestion: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {})
  return Customer
```