# Node.js, sequelize and Unknown column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I read this similar question:
[Sequelize Unknown column '*.createdAt' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386402/sequelize-unknown-column-createdat-in-field-list)

but the solution doesn't work for me!
Why?
This is my code:

```
 var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    cognome: DataTypes.STRING,
    nome: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.TEXT,
    stato: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ruolo: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, { 
    freezeTableName: true 
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  });
```

the error is:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `cognome`, `nome`, `email`, `data_nascita`, `password`, `cellulare`, `stato`, `blacklist`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Candidato` AS `Candidato`;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'createdAt' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing `{ timestamps: false }` as an additional param of `Sequelize.define` call, you should extend the existing (third) one with the corresponding property:

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {
  // model definition skipped
}, { 
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
});
```

... as it described in [the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#configuration).