# Sequelize column Table.createdAt does not exist

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have these two tables:

```
const AdminUser = sequelize.define('AdminUser', {
    adminUserId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, 
      unique: true, 
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    adminUsername: {
      type: 'citext',
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['super-admin', 'non-super-admin']  
    },
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }
  })

AdminUser.belongsToMany(MsTeam, {
      through: 'AdminUserTeam',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'adminUserId',
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
```

And

```
const MsTeam = sequelize.define('MsTeam', {
    teamId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, 
      unique: true, 
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    msTeamId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    msTeamName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }
  })

MsTeam.belongsToMany(models.AdminUser, {
      through: 'AdminUserTeam',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'teamId',
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
```

They have a n:m relationship through 'AdminUserTeam'.
Timestamps are enabled.

But a simple query like,

```
// Include team data
  const includeMsTeam = {
    model: MsTeam,
    through: {
      attributes: []
    },
    attributes: ['teamId', 'msTeamName']
  }
const users = await AdminUser.findAll({
    attributes: ['adminUserId', 'adminUsername'],
    limit: 10,
    offset: 10,
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    include: [includeMsTeam]
  })
```

fails with error,

```
{
    "error": "column AdminUser.createdAt does not exist"
}
```

Strangely, the query succeeds if I remove the `include` field

A solution to this was to disable timestamps as mentioned [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386402/sequelize-unknown-column-createdat-in-field-list). But what if I want to keep timestamps? How do I order by "createdAt" using associations?

Edit: Add SQL query

```
Executing (default): SELECT "AdminUser".*, "MsTeams"."teamId" AS "MsTeams.teamId", "MsTeams"."msTeamName" AS "MsTeams.msTeamName", "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam"."createdAt" AS "MsTeams.AdminUserTeam.createdAt", "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam"."updatedAt" AS "MsTeams.AdminUserTeam.updatedAt", "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam"."adminUserId" AS "MsTeams.AdminUserTeam.adminUserId", "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam"."teamId" AS "MsTeams.AdminUserTeam.teamId" FROM (SELECT "AdminUser"."adminUserId", "AdminUser"."adminUsername" FROM "AdminUsers" AS "AdminUser" WHERE "AdminUser"."role" = 'non-super-admin' AND ( SELECT "AdminUserTeam"."adminUserId" FROM "AdminUserTeam" AS "AdminUserTeam" INNER JOIN "MsTeams" AS "MsTeam" ON "AdminUserTeam"."teamId" = "MsTeam"."teamId" WHERE ("AdminUser"."adminUserId" = "AdminUserTeam"."adminUserId") LIMIT 1 ) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY "AdminUser"."createdAt" DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0) AS "AdminUser" LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "AdminUserTeam" AS "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam" INNER JOIN "MsTeams" AS "MsTeams" ON "MsTeams"."teamId" = "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam"."teamId") ON "AdminUser"."adminUserId" = "MsTeams->AdminUserTeam"."adminUserId" ORDER BY "AdminUser"."createdAt" DESC;
```

The error happens at,

```
ORDER BY "AdminUser"."createdAt" DESC
```

Comment: You can add `logging: console.log` to the options object to see what the generated SQL looks like in both situations. That might shed some light on what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the SQL query. I'm not sure why "AdminUser"."createdAt" does not exist. It is present in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that sequelize is generating a lot of subqueries and that `createdAt` is not visible to the top-most `ORDER BY`, try adding `subQuery: false` to the options object (the object that is the first argument of `findAll`). If that doesn't help, adding `createdAt` to `attributes` should work.

Comment: `subQuery: false` did it. Thanks.

Comment: how you add `subquery: false`, which options object are you referring to? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: The first argument of `findAll` is called "options" in the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-findAll). It has an undocumented property called `subQuery` and you use it like so: `Model.findAll({ subQuery: false, /* other stuff */ })`

Answer (score 2):

Sequelize will automatically add the attributes `createdAt` and `updatedAt` when you use the `define` method: https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/models-definition/

"If you do not want timestamps on your models, only want some timestamps, or you are working with an existing database where the columns are named something else, jump straight on to [configuration](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/models-definition/#configuration) to see how to do that"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```
sequelize.define('AdminUser', {
  // Columns
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

and check if there's createdAt column in REAL DATABASE as changing sequelize model doesn't reflect your change to REAL DATABASE automatically.

Comment: That did not work. Actually I never set timestamps to false so they were always enabled. Also, I can see the columns created in the table in the postgres UI tool so they are definitely present.

Comment: @Edl Oh, I thought you disabled it following SO answer you linked. What happens when you put createdAt column definition manually in AdminUser?

Comment: No change, I still get the same error. That SO answer actually mentioned that the problem occurs due to, "But when you join, each column of the joined table will be aliased".. I'm not sure what this is though

Answer (score 1):

`subQuery: false` wont work..!

But below code will work:

```
var user = sequelize.define('user', { /* bla */ }, {
  // don't add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps: false,
  // your other configuration here
});
```

Comment: Why would they remove the timestamps if they want to use the `createdAt` timestamp in the query, and stated in the question that they want to keep the timestamps? It's possible that you have a different use case / issue in your code where this helped, however this is not an answer to the user's question.