# Sequelize association belongsTo incorrect foreign key

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm currently running sequelize V6 migration and I'm not able to establish the correct association between tables.

User Model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  })

  user.associate = function(models){
    user.belongsTo(models.person, { foreignKey: 'personId' });
  return user
}
```

User table migration:

```js
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const common = require("../db/util/commonFields")(Sequelize);
    let fields = Object.assign(common, {
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      personId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'person',
          key: 'id',
        }
      },
    
    return queryInterface.createTable("User", fields);
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("User");
  },
};
```

Person Model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
  var Person = sequelize.define('person', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
  })
  Person.associate = function(models){
    Person.hasOne(models.user);
  }
  return Person
}
```

Person table migration:

```js
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const common = require("../db/util/commonFields")(Sequelize);
    let fields = Object.assign(common, {
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      }
    })
    return queryInterface.createTable("Person", fields);
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("Person");
  },
}
```

model/index.js

```js
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
var db        = {};
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = function(sequelize){
  fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
      return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    })
    .forEach(file => {
      var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, DataTypes);
      db[model.name] = model;
    });
  
  Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
  });
  
  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
  return db;
}
```

And I'm trying to do the following

```js
const models = require('../models')(sequelize, DataTypes);
const User = models.user;
const Person = models.person;
const result = await User.findAll({
  raw: true, 
  nest: true,
  include: [Person]
});
```

But I got the following errors

```
error: Failed to lift app: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'person.personId' in 'on clause'
    at Query.formatError (/Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:265:16)
    at Query.run (/Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:77:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async /Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:619:16
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (/Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:953:12)
    at async Function.findAll (/Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1753:21)
    at async Object.findAll (/Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/db/companyDao/UserDao.js:91:20)
    at async Object.main [as bootstrap] (/Users/echen/WeeCollege/WCApi/config/bootstrap.js:263:15)
```

According to the Sequelize documentation, it states

> The A.belongsTo(B) association means that a One-To-One relationship exists between A and B, with the foreign key being defined in the source model (A).

Now in my case, personId is defined in User so belongsTo should be using **user.personId join on person.id**. However, now it's looking for *person.personId*.

So I did a little digging and I found that when sequelize is generating join, it determines if association is an instance of BelongsTo like the following

```js
const attrLeft = association instanceof BelongsTo ?
  association.identifier :
  association.sourceKeyAttribute || left.primaryKeyAttribute;
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js#L1662

And it seems like the association is not an instanceof BelongsTo so it defaults to the primary key which is **id**.

Here's what **association** looks like in the debugger:

```
{
  source: class extends Model {},
  target: class extends Model {},
  options: {
    foreignKey: "personId",
    hooks: {
    },
    useHooks: false,
    timestamps: true,
    validate: {
    },
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: false,
    paranoid: false,
    rejectOnEmpty: false,
    whereCollection: null,
    schema: null,
    schemaDelimiter: "",
    defaultScope: {
    },
    scopes: {
    },
    indexes: [
    ],
    name: {
      plural: "people",
      singular: "person",
    },
    omitNull: false,
    sequelize: {...},
  },
  scope: undefined,
  isSelfAssociation: false,
  as: "person",
  associationType: "BelongsTo",
  isSingleAssociation: true,
  foreignKeyAttribute: {
  },
  foreignKey: "personId",
  identifier: "personId",
  identifierField: "personId",
  targetKey: "id",
  targetKeyField: "id",
  targetKeyIsPrimary: true,
  targetIdentifier: "id",
  associationAccessor: "person",
  accessors: {
    get: "getPerson",
    set: "setPerson",
    create: "createPerson",
  },
}{
  source: class extends Model {},
  target: class extends Model {},
  options: {
    foreignKey: "personId",
    hooks: {
    },
    useHooks: false,
    timestamps: true,
    validate: {
    },
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: false,
    paranoid: false,
    rejectOnEmpty: false,
    whereCollection: null,
    schema: null,
    schemaDelimiter: "",
    defaultScope: {
    },
    scopes: {
    },
    indexes: [
    ],
    name: {
      plural: "people",
      singular: "person",
    },
    omitNull: false,
    sequelize: {...},
  },
  scope: undefined,
  isSelfAssociation: false,
  as: "person",
  associationType: "BelongsTo",
  isSingleAssociation: true,
  foreignKeyAttribute: {
  },
  foreignKey: "personId",
  identifier: "personId",
  identifierField: "personId",
  targetKey: "id",
  targetKeyField: "id",
  targetKeyIsPrimary: true,
  targetIdentifier: "id",
  associationAccessor: "person",
  accessors: {
    get: "getPerson",
    set: "setPerson",
    create: "createPerson",
  },
}
```

The association looks right to me but why is it not an instanceof BelongsTo? Or am I using the association wrong?

Comment: Are you able to migrate the tables and then the query fails to run?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because I used sqlite rather than mysql I never replicated your error, but it looks like the problem lied with:
user.belongsTo(models.person, { foreignKey: 'personId' });  some of the associations try to add foreign keys to your database tables.  here sequelize thinks Person.personId already exists and assumes that when it writes queries.  If you don't provide a foreign key it tries to auto-generate one.  I find the manual obtuse and figure it out by watching the queries sequelize outputs to the console.
Here is similar working code:
assuming:

```
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli
npm install sequelize -save
npx sequelize init
npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name Person  --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string  //also something to get a user model
```

I haven't found a way to add foreign keys and assosciations other than editing the migration and model files so change the appropriate files to:

```
'use strict';
// user migration
//removed const common as I had no idea what it did or why
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: { //migrations create tables so need primary keys
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      personId: { //each user is a person relationship 
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'person',
          key: 'id',
        }}
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

```
'use strict';
//person migration
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('People', {
      id: {  //migrations create tables so need primary keys 
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('People');
  }
};
```

```
'use strict';
//person.js
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Person extends Model {
      static associate(models) {
      this.hasOne(models.User,{foreignKey: "personId"});  //see https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html //creates functions and foreign key in user
    }
  };
  Person.init({
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false, // stops sequelize from trying to get created columns see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386402/sequelize-unknown-column-createdat-in-field-list
    modelName: 'Person'
  });
  return Person;
};
```

```
'use strict';
//user.js
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
      static associate(models) {
      this.belongsTo(models.Person, {foreignKey: "personId"}); //creates assosciation functions without creating a foreign key
    }
  };
  User.init({
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    personId: { 
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'person',
        key: 'id',
      }}
  }, {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    modelName: 'User'
  });
  return User;
};
```

```
//index.js in main file to test code
const db = require('./models');
const asyncouterFunction = async function() {
const User = db.User;
const Person = db.Person;
await Person.create({firstName: "James", lastName:"Kirk"});
await Person.create({firstName: "Leonard", lastName:"Mcoy"});
const People = await Person.findAll();
console.log(JSON.stringify(People))
}
asyncouterFunction();
```

Comment: If I define models the way you do, it gets the following error during association
`error: Failed to lift app: Error: user.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`

What's weird is that if I define user model your way and person model my way it works??? It looks like the model `sequelize.define` returns is not the same as Model from `require('sequelize')`. Any idea why this is?

Comment: try replacing this with user.  This has issues at times.  Or just use your way with the correct association.  The problem was hasone was auto-generating a foreign key and/or foreignKey was declared but sequelize thought it was in the wrong table.  your code works just correct the association.